# How to write a test case to check if an email string is valid in Mocha / Chai in Javascript?

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I am new to JavaScript testing. I want to know how to write test cases for scenarios like the name field should not contain any number or the one other example I asked above.
Are there any good practices to follow?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the link below to get some examples. I normally follow this link while writing the test scripts.

https://www.chaijs.com/guide/styles/#expect

Comment: Thank you. That helped!